HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error. IIS Web Core
So I'm getting 500.19 error trying to publish and browse a simple web site to IIS.  Here is my Web.config file
`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
          <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
          </handlers>
          <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\TestAspRazor.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
      </location>
    </configuration>`

error
I have allowed permissions on the wwwroot folders/sub-folders/files to NETWORK SERVICES, IIS_IUSRS and the relevant application pool. i have also installed the .NET Core Hosting Bundle, but no luck.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.
Unfortunately that duplicate question does not resolve my issue. before flagging this question again, can you please understand what the issue is. Thanks in advance.

Did you check the event logs, like the error message suggested?

Yes, but there is nothing relevant there.

One way I like to validate these sorts of errors is to open up an admin command prompt, cd to the directory that contains your app, then run dotnet TestAspRazor.dll. If the app fails to start, it should give you a helpful error message.

Yeah, that a good tip, messages i got were..... Now listening on: http://localhost:5000 and Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. No error messages though... I found that i could view the web page at http://localhost:5000. so assume its all working OK.

Have you tried running an iisreset?

Yeah, tried that too, i think it might be a permissions issue. I'll have to keep trying, but thanks for your help.
